# Recurrent security log in my Symfony2 application: 'security.WARNING: Username "" could not be found.'

Tags: security, logging, symfony

I have a Symfony2 (`2.0.19`) application with the `FOSUserBundle` that I extends with a custom `UserManager` class because it has to load data from an old database which can not be migrated for now. Everything works well, users can login, access their dashboard, disconnect... But I have this recurrent warning in the `prod.log` log file:

```
[2012-12-05 18:16:45] security.WARNING: Username "" could not be found. [] []
```

This is caused when trying to log with a user-name that can't be found. So the error is "*normal*".

This warning is not very useful as the user-name is not logged. So, I'd like to remove it without changing the error report level of the `prod` environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we commit our vendor (not a good practice but we've been asked to do this) I have deleted this log which was useless.